Maven Build Error : Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.2:clean failed
I've looked into this issue as the title suggest, but I'm still don't know what I should do. While trying to build an executable jar file, one of the plugins 'maven-clean-plugin' cannot be resolved.
Error Message :

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.2:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1 (absent): Could not transfer artifact javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1 from/to the 

Pipeline doesn't allow to download vulnerable dependencies from Custom repository. And for security reasons, custom repository cannot be modified / removed .
How can I exclude the dependency 'javax.inject' from my pom file?
Pom File :
          ` <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>`

I tried to add the dependency to the maven-clean-plugin like below :
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version> <!--- One and only version available for this dependency -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

@aled what kind of additional data would you need to reproduce the described limited network access, where central repo is not directly available? And I mean it seriously, what parts exactly should be added, like "the complete pom.xml", "the complete settings.xml", so that the OP has a better idea of what data would help to track down the problem.

Complete pom.xml would be a good start.

I don't see either that javax.inject has known vulnerabilities or that the maven-clean-plugin makes direct use of it.
It is a dependency of maven-core, which is a provided dependency of the maven-clean-plugin, that means, the calling maven installation has to provide it. Probably your maven installation is broken.
Try to clean your local repository (maybe located in ~/.m2/repository where ~ stands for your user home folder; or in another position, if you reconfigured it in your maven settings.xml file).
Try to reinstall maven - don't use the maven wrapper if you used it before, I had troubles using that in an environment where network access is limited. Try to use a recent version of maven (at the time of writing the most current stable version is 3.9.7 - of maven, not of the plugin!)
